# Lotus Notes external doc files search text

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotusscript

By using the follow code i can find a strin in eny external file ( .txt ).
Function  "funcCheckIfStrinInFileExist" use Instr function to find position of the string
and return 0 if an integer if string exist in myRecord (see bellow ).

Is there any way to search a .doc file (or .docx) , because (or .PDF !!!)  if file is word document return error.

Thanks in advance.

```
Do While fileName$ <> ""
    varCheckIfStrinInFileExist  =  funcCheckIfStrinInFileExist( fileName, myString )
    
    If varCheckIfStrinInFileExist    Then 
        Messagebox "i found the text in file  : " + fileName
    End If
    fileName$ = Dir$()
Loop 

'************************************************************************
funcCheckIfStrinInFileExist ( fileName, myString ) as integer 

.......................................
Do Until Eof(filenum%)
        'Read a line of data
    Input #filenum%, myRecord

    positionOfChar  = Instr(myRecord$, varString)
    
    If  Cint(positionOfChar)  >  0 Then
        funcCheckIfStrinInFileExist = True 
        Close filenum
        Exit Function
    End If
Loop
```

Comment: If I  can save it (.doc) as   .txt  this can solve my request .

Comment: You'd have to use a third party package like Apache Tika. This will inevitably mean you'd have to write some Java but it can be done https://tika.apache.org/

Comment: Doc files are "binary" files, not text, so you might try to open them as binary. Unfortunately that also means that you cannot read lines, and that you have to deal with the internal doc format yourself. Same for PDF. A suggestion: wouldn't it be better to call an external application to do the searching on the O/S level?

Comment: For Word documents you could open the word document using VBA calls from lotusscript, and use the VBA "Find.execute" method.  It won't be quick, but it's feasible. I've never tried it in VBA (and I don't know if it's possible), but you may be able to open a PDF in Word. The rendering isn't good, but that's not a problem if you're just searching for text.  You could then use find.execute like in a Word doc.